# Laravel Nova isn't using the array key as the option value in filters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I created this filter for Nova v4.32.11:

```
class AccountFilter extends Filter
{
    public function apply(Request $request, $query, $value)
    {
        return $query->where('account_id', $value);
    }

    public function options(Request $request)
    {
        return Account::all()
            ->sortBy('name')
            ->mapWithKeys(function ($account) {
                return [$account->id => $account->name];
            })
            ->toArray();
    }
}
```

If I `dd()` the array being returned in `options()` it looks like this:

```
[
    1 => 'Foo',
    2 => 'Bar',
    3 => 'Baz',
]
```

However, if I inspect the element in Nova I see this for the select options:

```
<select dusk="Account Filter-select-filter" class="w-full block form-control form-select form-control-sm form-select-bordered">
<option value="">—</option>
<option value="Foo">Foo</option>
<option value="Bar">Bar</option>
<option value="Baz">Baz</option>
</select>
```

If I `dd()` the `$value` in `apply()` I see that value is indeed the account name instead of the ID as I'd expect from the array returned for the options list.

I decided to manually return exactly what I pasted above as the output...

The code:
[image: manually overriding the options code]

The output in Chrome:
[image: screenshot of Chrome inspection on rendered options]

What is wrong here?

Comment: Something is wrong with your `options` method, the documentation states that you can share the key and value and will be used as you expected it https://nova.laravel.com/docs/filters/defining-filters.html

Comment: @matiaslauriti yes, this is the behavior I was expecting, however, it doesn't work. I pasted this here verbatim from my own code. If I `dd` the return value of the `options` method, I get exactly the structure of numeric keys and text values that I use in every other option in my resources, as well as what matches the docs (obviously the foo bar output is me manually sanitizing the data).

Comment: I see the issue. When defining a list of options for a select in a Nova resource, you do it `option value => option text` but when defining for a Nova filter it is backwards `option text => option value`. Also, if you want numeric values, you have to cast them as a string or Nova will strip them out and just use the text as the value instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need to use the account ID for filtering, but Laravel Nova is using the account name instead. One workaround is to use a custom component for the filter. This way, you can control the select options' value and display text separately.

First, you need to create a new Vue component. This component will be used for the filter. In this component, you can specify the value and the display text of the select options separately.

Here is an example of how you can create this component:

```js
<template>
    <select class="form-control form-select" v-model="value">
        <option v-for="(name, id) in options" :value="id">{{ name }}</option>
    </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['options', 'value'],
}
</script>
```

Next, you need to register this component in your Nova service provider:

```php
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Nova::script('custom-filter', __DIR__.'/../dist/js/filter.js');
    Nova::style('custom-filter', __DIR__.'/../dist/css/filter.css');

    Nova::provideToScript([
        'custom-filter' => new CustomFilter,
    ]);
}
```

Finally, you can use this component in your `AccountFilter` class:

```php
class AccountFilter extends Filter
{
    public function apply(Request $request, $query, $value)
    {
        return $query->where('account_id', $value);
    }

    public function options(Request $request)
    {
        return Account::all()
            ->sortBy('name')
            ->mapWithKeys(function ($account) {
                return [$account->id => $account->name];
            })
            ->toArray();
    }

    public function components()
    {
        return [
            'custom-filter' => new CustomFilter,
        ];
    }
}
```

In this modified version, the `apply` method filters by the account ID, and the `options` method returns an array where the keys are the IDs and the values are the names. The `components` method specifies that the `custom-filter` component should be used for this filter. This way, the value selected in the Nova interface will match the value used in the `apply` method.

Comment: Unfortunately, name is not unique per account and the related table has an `account_id` foreign key not a `name` foreign key, which is why the ID is necessary for this relationship filter to search the `account_id` col.

Comment: This is also messing up every other filter that I need the where clause to be an ID, not the name of the item in the list which is only displayed for the sake of the user to know what they are selecting.

Comment: Thanks. Very bizarre you have to create a custom component for something so simple. This almost feels like a bug.